# Нажать кнопочку програмно на сайте с помощью winforms

Tags: c#, html, winforms

Есть приложение, в нем компонент `WebBrowser` и кнопочка, хочу, что бы при нажатии кнопочки в приложении нажималась кнопочка на сайте. Но структура сайта довольно непростая и не могу подобраться к нужной кнопочке. Вот структура сайта:

[image: структура сайта]

Мне нужно добраться к любой из кнопочек с тегом `'a'`, вот код:

```
HtmlWindow frames = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
var elements1 = frames.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("table");

foreach (HtmlElement element in elements1)
{
    string attrValue = element.GetAttribute("alt");
    if (attrValue == "myAttr")
    {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Что не так делаю? Как правильно добраться до нужной кнопочки?

Comment: А что именно происходит? Сколько элементов находит ваш код?

Comment: Какие элементы Вы имеете в виду ? Я пытаюсь найти строку, в которой есть элемент alt  с неким значением, оно его не находит. Видимо потому, что оно очень глубоко зарыто.

Comment: Ну, да, вы ж смотрите только на первом уровне. Попробуйте `foreach (HtmlElement element in element1.GetElementsByTagName(тут тег вашей кнопки))`.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду в цикле еще один цикл? И еще , с именами переменных Вы не напутали? Просто не понятно, откуда element1 появился? Скиньте пожалуйста пример кода полностью.

Comment: А, ну да, точно, вложенный цикл. Первый цикл получает все таблицы, второй цикл — все кнопки внутри каждой из таблиц. Впрочем, вы правы, по сути вам внешний цикл не нужен, делайте просто цикл по всем кнопкам, а не по таблицам.

Comment: Погодите, тогда я не понял, а как одним циклом я могу пробежать по всем кнопкам? Точнее, как я могу получить доступ сразу ко кнопке?

Comment: Ну, точно так же. Какой тег у кнопки? Вот и делайте `Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName(тут тег кнопки);` по идее. Наверное, `"button"`?

Comment: Это кнопка выглядит как ссылка на картинку, посмотрите выше скрин.

Comment: Уже пробовал, был код тот же самый как и в вопросе, только вместо "table" было "a" - не получилось. Опять таки, думаю что потому что, глубоко зарыто.

Comment: В общем я потестировал, и понял, что уровень вложенности никак не влияет, те кнопочки, которые я пытаюсь нажать сделаны как картинки со ссылкой, если же нажимать обычные кнопочки "input" то все работает прекрасно.

Comment: Ну, понятно, что получив `a`, вам нужно ещё искать `img` внутри.

Comment: Но как именно нажать на `a`, я не в курсе.

Comment: Жаль( Ладно, можете кто подскажет чего, Спасибо за советы!

Comment: Пишут, что `InvokeMember("click")` должно работать: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3419306/276994

Comment: Ну вот я пробую, ни на одну картиночную кнопку не жмет, если кнопочка Input, то никаких проблем нету. И не важно какой уровень вложенности.

Comment: Покажите код. Вы жмёте, надеюсь, не на картинку, а на `a`?

Comment: Код в вопросе.
Вы знаете, довольно тривиально решил свою проблему, сымитировал нажатие кнопки как маус клик, т.е. поменял     
`private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`     
на     
`private void button3_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39153/discussion-between---and-vladd).